# How to get country wise max populated city with population count

Tags: sql

I am currently searching for a SQL query that does the following:

I have a table of all cities worldwide with their countries and population.

e.g. the table "city" (some columns)

| name | country | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | Germany | 3640000 |
| New York | USA | 8419000 |
| Hamburg | Germany | 1841000 |
| Los Angeles | USA | 3967000 |

I know need to find the city with the city with the highest population per country.

e.g. the desired result

| name | population | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | 3640000 | Germany |
| New York | 8419000 | USA |

The problem is that this query:

```
SELECT name, MAX(population) FROM city GROUP BY country
```

wouldn't return the appropriate name of the city. I know why that happens but am not sure how I could solve it in another way.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Don't tag spam. Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANSI SQL solution using subquery almost for any rdbms:

```
 create table city (name varchar(50),country    varchar(50), population int);
 insert into city values('Berlin'   ,'Germany', 3640000);
 insert into city values('New York' ,'USA', 8419000);
 insert into city values('Hamburg'  ,'Germany', 1841000);
 insert into city values('Los Angeles'  ,'USA', 3967000);
```

Query:

```
 select name, population, country from city c
 where population=(select max(population ) from city a where  a.country=c.country)
```

Output:

| name | population | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | 3640000 | Germany |
| New York | 8419000 | USA |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d249a0a0a61418eff5419360a242f8ac)*

Answer (score 1):

you need to tag your dbms , but this works in most of databases including mariadb , using window function will ovoid hitting city table twice:

```
select * from 
  (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by country order by population desc) rn
   from city
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @zunkelty  missed sub query alias , it should be good now , see updated asnwer

Answer (score 0):

you can use "NOT EXISTS"

```
SELECT * from country a
where not exists
(
select 1 from country b 
where a.country = b.country
and b.population > a.population
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from city where (country, population) in
(
select country, max(population) from city group by country
);
```